# Dynamically Create Root element and child element

Tags: android, web-services

i developed webservice based android application...when i send request like

```
String Outlet=new String();
        Outlet = "<PMS><EMENU><DATETIME></DATETIME><ID>1</ID><REQTYPE>OUTLETID</REQTYPE><OUTLETID>AD</OUTLETID></EMENU></PMS>";
request.addProperty("Outlet", Outlet);
```

it will give the answer perfectly....but i have a value of OUTLETID in a string like

```
String Outlet="AD";
```

so now how can i send request to webservice using soap.....
then how to add root element and child for the string Outlet...

this is my webservice method coding.....

```
public string GetOutletID(string outlet)
    {
        xDoc.LoadXml("<PMS></PMS>");
        XmlNode Root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        XmlElement head = xDoc.CreateElement("EMENU");
        Root.AppendChild(head);

        XmlElement dt = xDoc.CreateElement("DATETIME");
        dt.InnerText = Date;
        head.AppendChild(dt);

        elem = null;
        elem = xDoc.CreateElement("ID");
        elem.InnerText = "1";
        head.AppendChild(elem);

        elem = null;
        elem = xDoc.CreateElement("REQTYPE");
        elem.InnerText = "OUTLETID";
        head.AppendChild(elem);

        elem = null;
        elem = xDoc.CreateElement("OUTLETID");
        elem.InnerText = outlet;
        head.AppendChild(elem);
        return xDoc.InnerXml.ToString();

    }
```

thanks in advance....please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking for is to 'concatenate' the value some string variable contains then why don't you simple do this:

```
String Outlet = "AD";
Outlet = "<PMS><EMENU><DATETIME></DATETIME><ID>1</ID><REQTYPE>OUTLETID</REQTYPE><OUTLETID>" + Outlet + "</OUTLETID></EMENU></PMS>";
```

Comment: can you please mark this as an accepted answer then, you an do this by clicking the check mark on left? thanks